# How can I get the jmeter result from java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I integrated jmeter in the java code, now I can execute the test normally, but the result can only be output on the console, I want to get the test result as a file or a string, what should I do? I try to use the logger.setFilename and demo_result is a blank file,but i get the result like that:

1678900803115,1,,200,,Example Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,189,120,1,1,1,0,0
1678900803117,1,,200,,Example Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,189,120,1,1,1,0,0
1678900803119,1,,200,,Example Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,189,120,1,1,1,0,0

**how can i get other result** like "summary =      3 in 00:00:00 =   46.9/s Avg:     1 Min:     1 Max:     1 Err:     0 (0.00%)"?
This is my code.

```java
public static void initJmeter(){
        StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // 设置不适用gui的方式调用jmeter
        System.setProperty(JMeter.JMETER_NON_GUI, "true");
        // 设置jmeter.properties文件，我们将jmeter文件存放在resources中，通过classload
        //String path = TestPlanLauncher.class.getClassLoader().getResource("jmeter.properties").getPath();
        String path = "D:/Programming/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.5/bin/jmeter.properties";
        File jmeterPropertiesFile = new File(path);
        if (jmeterPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterPropertiesFile.getPath());
            HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();
            TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
            HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = createHTTPSamplerProxy();
            LoopController loopController = createLoopController();
            ThreadGroup threadGroup = createThreadGroup();
            threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
            HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
            threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);
            Summariser summer = null;
            String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
            if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
            }
            ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
            logger.setFilename("D:/Programming/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.5/result/demo_result");
            testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

            standardJMeterEngine.configure(testPlanTree);
            standardJMeterEngine.run();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how do your `createHTTPSamplerProxy()`, `createLoopController()`, etc. look like but if you take the following class from [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) sample project as a reference:

```
package com.blazemeter.demo;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class JMeterFromScratch {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        File jmeterHome = new File(System.getProperty("jmeter.home"));
        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
            File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");
            if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                //JMeter Engine
                StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
                JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
                JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
                JMeterUtils.initLocale();

                // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
                HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

                // First HTTP Sampler - open example.com
                HTTPSamplerProxy examplecomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
                examplecomSampler.setDomain("example.com");
                examplecomSampler.setPort(80);
                examplecomSampler.setPath("/");
                examplecomSampler.setMethod("GET");
                examplecomSampler.setName("Open example.com");
                examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
                examplecomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


                // Second HTTP Sampler - open blazemeter.com
                HTTPSamplerProxy blazemetercomSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
                blazemetercomSampler.setDomain("blazemeter.com");
                blazemetercomSampler.setPort(80);
                blazemetercomSampler.setPath("/");
                blazemetercomSampler.setMethod("GET");
                blazemetercomSampler.setName("Open blazemeter.com");
                blazemetercomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
                blazemetercomSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


                // Loop Controller
                LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
                loopController.setLoops(1);
                loopController.setFirst(true);
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
                loopController.initialize();

                // Thread Group
                ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
                threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
                threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
                threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
                threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

                // Test Plan
                TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
                testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

                // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
                testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
                HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
                threadGroupHashTree.add(blazemetercomSampler);
                threadGroupHashTree.add(examplecomSampler);

                // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
                SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + slash + "example.jmx"));

                //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
                // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
                Summariser summer = null;
                String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
                if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
                }


                // Store execution results into a .jtl file
                String logFile = jmeterHome + slash + "example.jtl";
                ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
                logger.setFilename(logFile);
                testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

                // Run Test Plan
                jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                jmeter.run();

                System.out.println("Test completed. See " + jmeterHome + slash + "example.jtl file for results");
                System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + slash + "example.jmx");
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

        System.err.println("jmeter.home property is not set or pointing to incorrect location");
        System.exit(1);


    }
}
```

and run it you will see that `example.jtl` file contains some metrics:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1678906535000,210,Open example.com,200,OK,Example Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1610,108,1,1,http://example.com/,206,0,102
1678906535211,47,Open blazemeter.com,301,Moved Permanently,Example Thread Group 1-1,,true,,381,111,1,1,http://blazemeter.com/,47,0,23
```

The summarizer output will go to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) and to [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files

You might also be interested in [JMeter DSL](https://JMeter%20DSL:%20Bringing%20Performance%20Testing%20Closer%20to%20Developers)

Comment: thank you very much!but i have another question,why i can't open the example.jmx by gui?the err message as follows:class org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup cannot be cast to class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase (org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup and org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.jmeter.DynamicClassLoader @3b07d329)